# On Windows 10, the Cancel object never returns RPC_E_CALL_COMPLETE

Tags: winapi, mfc, com

In our application that we've had for 15+ years, we have a type of progress bar. 
 This progress bar is for long lasting C++ operations and there is also the case for when we make a COM call and it takes a long time for the COM call to return. 
 In general, we want the user to know that something is taking a long time to complete and give him a chance to cancel if he thinks it is taking too much time.

For COM operations, many years ago we implemented a custom IMessageFilter for COM calls that take too long.  We would like the user to be able to cancel but also for the prompt to cancel go away on its own when the operation completes.  It has been working fine for years.  Most of our customers are conservative and are still running Windows 7.  Recently a customer using Windows 10 has found an issue where a COM call on Windows 10 never seems to never finish.

Our progress bar comes up and the progress control cycles and recycles, but the operation never seems to finish.  After investigating it, it seems that the ICancelMethodCalls::TestCancel() method always returns RPC_S_CALLPENDING, it never returns RPC_E_CALL_COMPLETE.  On Windows 7, previous versions of Windows, and Windows 8.1, it works fine, but not on Windows 10.

I created a minimal test solution in Visual Studio 2013 that demonstrates the problem.  One project is an ATL server, and the other project is an MFC client application.  A link to a zip file of a sample solution is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1dkchplsi7d6tda/MyTimeOutServer.zip?dl=0

Basically the ATL server has a property that sets a delay, and a method that just waits the delay length.  The purpose is to simulate a COM operation that is taking too long.

```
interface IMyTimoutServer : IDispatch{
   [propget, id(1), helpstring("Timeout value in milliseconds")] HRESULT TimeOut([out, retval] LONG* pVal);
   [propput, id(1), helpstring("Timeout value in milliseconds")] HRESULT TimeOut([in] LONG newVal);
   [id(2)] HRESULT DoTimeOut([out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL* Result);
};
```

The next important thing is the IMessageFilter in the client application.  At some point, someone decided it was good to derive from COleMessageFilter, the default MFC implementation.  (Let's not argue whether that is a good idea.)

The important methods of the the class are the MessagePending() and MyNotResponding().

```
DWORD CMyMessageFilter::XMyMessageFilter::MessagePending(HTASK htaskCallee, DWORD dwTickCount, DWORD dwPendingType)
{
   METHOD_PROLOGUE_EX(CMyMessageFilter, MyMessageFilter);
   ASSERT_VALID(pThis);

   MSG msg;
   if (dwTickCount > pThis->m_nTimeout && !pThis->m_bUnblocking && pThis->IsSignificantMessage(&msg))
   {
      if (pThis->m_bEnableNotResponding)
      {
         pThis->m_bUnblocking = TRUE;    // avoid reentrant calls

         // eat all mouse and keyboard messages in our queue
         while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_MOUSEFIRST, AFX_WM_MOUSELAST, PM_REMOVE | PM_NOYIELD));
         while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE | PM_NOYIELD));

         // show not responding dialog
         pThis->m_dwTickCount = dwTickCount;
         bool bCancel = pThis->MyNotResponding(htaskCallee) == RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED;

         pThis->m_bUnblocking = FALSE;

         return bCancel ? PENDINGMSG_CANCELCALL : PENDINGMSG_WAITNOPROCESS; // if canceled, the COM call will return RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED
      }
   }

   // don't process re-entrant messages
   if (pThis->m_bUnblocking)
      return PENDINGMSG_WAITDEFPROCESS;

   // allow application to process pending message
   if (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_NOREMOVE | PM_NOYIELD))
      pThis->OnMessagePending(&msg); // IK: could also return a value from extended OnMessagePending() to cancel the call

   // by default we return pending MSG wait
   return PENDINGMSG_WAITNOPROCESS;
}
```

After a timeout, we display a status type window that updates in the NotMyResponding() method.

```
int CMyMessageFilter::MyNotResponding(HTASK hTaskBusy)
{
   TRY
   {
      CComPtr<ICancelMethodCalls> pCancel;
      HRESULT hRes = ::CoGetCancelObject(0, IID_ICancelMethodCalls, (void**)&pCancel);
      ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hRes)); // COM should automatically create Cancel objects for pending calls [both on client and server]

      if (pCancel == NULL)
      {
         return COleBusyDialog::retry;
      }

      m_pFrame->EnableWindow(FALSE);
      CMyCancelDlg dlg;
      dlg.Create(CMyCancelDlg::IDD);
      dlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
      HWND hWndDlg = dlg.GetSafeHwnd();

      do
      {
         MSG msg;
         for (int i = 0; i < 100 && PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE | PM_NOYIELD); ++i)
         {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
         }

         if (dlg.StepAndCheckCancel())
         {
            dlg.DestroyWindow();
            m_pFrame->EnableWindow(TRUE);
            return RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED; // signals to MessagePending() that the COM call should be cancelled
         }

         Sleep(250); // this call has been pending for many seconds now... sleep for some time to avoid CPU utilization by this loop and yield if needed

         hRes = pCancel->TestCancel();

      } while (hRes == RPC_S_CALLPENDING);

      ATLASSERT(hRes == RPC_E_CALL_COMPLETE);

      dlg.DestroyWindow();
      m_pFrame->EnableWindow(TRUE);

   }
   END_TRY

   return RPC_E_CALL_COMPLETE;
}
```

Basically, in MyNotResponding(), we create a Cancel object, create a window with a cancel button, pump messsages, and look for either a press on the cancel button or if TestCancel() returns something other than RPC_S_CALLPENDING.

Well, on Windows 10, it stays in the loop and RPC_S_CALLPENDING is always returned from TestCancel().

Has anyone seen anything like this on Windows 10?  Are we doing something wrong that we are really only getting lucky on Windows 7?

The default implementation of the MFC puts up an OLEUIBusy dialog which pumps messages.  It just never tests the cancel object.

Comment: This implies that your dialog's Cancel button is never being clicked, and/or nobody is calling [`ICancelMethodCalls::Cancel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680711.aspx)  on long-running COM methods (does your dialog call `ICancelMethodCalls::Cancel()` when its Cancel button is clicked?)

Comment: The StepAndCheckCancel() method steps the progress bar and checks for a cancel.  That is not the problem.  On Windows 10, the TestCancel() method always returns RPC_S_CALLPENDING.

Comment: That does not change what I said.  You keep asking about `TestCancel()`, but did you verify that your Cancel button handler is being executed? Does `StepAndCheckCancel()` ever return true? You did not show its implementation. And you didn't answer my questions - does your button handler call `ICancelMethodCalls::Cancel()`? If not, why not?  What exactly are you expecting to trigger `TestCancel()` to return something other than `RPC_S_CALLPENDING`?  Where is THAT code exactly?

Comment: StepAndCheckCancel() returns true when the cancel button is pressed. Code is in the link if you want.  It's barking up a tree.  It works.  Even if I never press the button, eventually the COM call should succeed and TestCancel() return RPC_CALL_COMPLETE.  The COM runtime has the Cancel object which is gotten with CoGetCancelObject().  It should not be necessary for my code to do anything with the Cancel object except to call TestCancel() on it.  If I press the cancel button, I return RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED eventually through IFilter::MessagePending which signals to COM to cancel the call.

Comment: It is not advisable to post your code on another download site. Please [edit] your question to show ALL relevant code on THIS site, where it belongs.

Comment: Besides, there is no guarantee that the COM method you are trying to wait on even uses the Cancel object you are monitoring. How is the object being marshaled? "*For objects that use **standard marshaling**, COM automatically creates cancel objects and implements `ICancelMethodCalls` on them. For objects that use **custom marshaling**, you must implement your own corresponding cancel object and implement `ICancelMethodCalls` on that object.*"  Since your code works in Windows 7 and earlier, but is broken on Windows 10, is is possible that the COM object's marshaling has changed?

Comment: If the object does not implement the Cancel object or the system does not do it for me, then at the beginning of the routine above, CoGetCancelObject() will fail and I will return immediately and it will continue processing the IMessageFilter::MessagePending().

The problem is not with pushing/not pushing the Cancel button.  It is that even after the COM method has completed, it never signals that it is completed.

I put all the RELEVANT code I thought necessary.  It is not really possible to put ALL the code for two separate projects, an ATL server and MFC app in a posting.

Comment: `CoGetCancelObject()` only returns a system-provided cancel object, it won't return an implementation-provided object unless that object is registered via `CoSetCancelObject()`. `CoGetCancelObject()` also "*does not locate cancel objects for asynchronous calls*". It would be helpful if you explained what kind of long-running operation you are actually trying to cancel.

Comment: I am making a simple cross process synchonous COM call to a method of a COM server.  The ATL server I provided is for demo purposes.  It could be a call to some COM process that takes times out. The sample ATL server relies on the default Cancel object.